# Create table works in MySql but not in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

This works in MySql-

```
create database CarRentalCo;
use CarRentalCo;
create table LuxuryCars(rate varchar(5));
```

I tried to do the same thing in java, using jdbc and I got an error-

```
//Some code here
String query = 
"create database CarRentalCo; "
"use CarRentalCo; "
"create table LuxuryCars(rate varchar(5)); "
//some code here
executeUpdate(query);
```

Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'use CarRentalCo; create table LuxuryCars(rate varchar(5))' at line 1
```

Comment: One query per `executeUpdate() `

Comment: @shubhansh -  execute() fails too. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some jdbc drivers have problems including a ; at the end of the statement, but the main problem is only one statement per executeUpdate.

Also i don't think it's a good idea to change the database connection through a query when you're using jdbc. Should be part of the url connect string.

Comment: Yes ! that works. I executed each query separately. I wonder why can't the API execute statements exactly like the way it is done in MySql workbench.

Comment: Because MySQL workbench is a product, JDBC is a standardized api. I guess MySQL workbench parses your statements internally and executes them one at a time like other DB interfaces.

Comment: Thanks ! I was thinking, why could they not make it work like the Workbench - would be more intuitive that way.